# Bluetooth Headset / Headphones conflict

Tags: windows, audio, bluetooth

I've noticed this problem with a few different headsets.

I have a pair of Bluetooth Headphones with a mic. This appears to Windows as a Bluetooth Headset and another Bluetooth Headphones device.

The problem is that if both are connected to the computer (which happens by default) the Headphones do not get any audio. Once I "Disconnect" the headset device, the headphones work flawlessly.

The next problem is when I want to use VOIP. The audio quality drops to sub-phone quality.

How do I let Windows know to prioritize audio output to the headphones, and only accept the "Mic" portion of the headset? Or at the very least, let them both work simultaneously and switch from one to the other as necessary.